Metabase: Query to extract last 7 days of data or from the filters
I want to write a query in Metabase where by default it would extract data for the last 7 days but if the filters are selected it would extract based on the filters. Can someone help with this?
Could find a solution for this

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please try to use the field filter for your metabase question it is the best date filter for getting predefined date ranges.
Here, is the detailed article on how to use it: Metabase Date filter
I have been using this for all my question and it gives the best result. This will allow you to set the default to 7 days.
